# Efficient way of counting unique occurances?

Tags: optimization, sqlite, query-optimization

I've got a database table of updates to items `(item_id, updated_time, key, value)`. I would like to know how many times each item is getting updated. My current query is:

```
SELECT item_id, count(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT item_id, updated_time FROM updates)
GROUP BY item_id;
```

The problem is this runs very slowly. My table has 2451 items and ~8 million updates, the database currently only covers a single day. I have indices on `item_id`, `updated_time` and `(item_id, updated_time)`.

Can i make this query run faster in sqlite? Would moving to something less 'lite' help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery prevents index optimizations in the outer query.
Use a single query, like this:

```
SELECT item_id,
       count(DISTINCT updated_time)
FROM updates
GROUP BY item_id
```

With a sufficiently recent SQLite version, this will run from the covering index (check with `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`).